# Finding function by constraints

Tags: function-construction, mathematical-optimization, constraint

I have the following coefficient finding problem:

```
f[x] := a * Log[b*x + c] + d
```

Constraints:

- f[0] = 1
- f[80] = 0.5

I want to find the coefficients of f that adhere to these constraints. What is the easiest way to formulate this problem in Mathematica?

Ideally, I would tell Mathematica just the constraints and which functions it is allowed to use, i.e. to not have to type out a * Log[b*x + c] + d.

Comment: You have some basic syntax problems. First, function definition should be done with an underscore (i.e. `f[x_]:=...`). Second, I think you meant `b x` (which is equivalent to `b*x`) and not `bx`. Also `Log` is the function, and not `log`, and calling functions is done with square brackets, and not round ones.

Comment: Lastly, you have 4 unknowns (`a,b,c,d`) and only 2 constraints. Therefore you cannot "solve" and find the unknowns, as there are infinitely many of them what will adhere to the constraints.

Comment: @bobby, somehow I'm not sure fixing OP's syntax errors for him is a good idea…

Comment: @J. M., you have a point. I am sorry. Would rolling it back be a good idea or would it just be confusing?

Comment: @bobby, since we're here, we might as well leave it be, tho that has the effect of making yohbs's otherwise fine comment seem impertinent.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion guys, I didn't mean to write the function out in Mathematica syntax - should have done that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will be an infinite number of functions. You could approach as follows:

```
f[a_, b_, c_, d_, x_] := a*Log[b*x + c] + d
```

then

```
FindInstance[{f[a, b, c, d, 0] == 1,
  f[a, b, c, d, 80] == 0.5}, {a, b, c, d}, Reals]
```

this yields:

```
{{a -> 7.95441, b -> -0.098772, c -> 1297/10, d -> -(377/10)}}
```

or

```
sol = First[Quiet@Solve[{f[a, b, c, d, 0] == 1,
      f[a, b, c, d, 80] == 0.5}, {a, b, c, d}, Reals]];
```

Note `sol` is a conditional expression:

```
{c -> ConditionalExpression[-((
     80. 2.71828^(1/a) b)/(-1. + 2.71828^(1/a))) + (
    80. Sqrt[2.71828^(1/a) b^2])/
    Abs[-1. + 2.71828^(1/a)], (a > 0 && b < 0) || (a < 0 && b > 0)], 
 d -> ConditionalExpression[
   1. - 1. a Log[-((80. 2.71828^(1/a) b)/(-1. + 2.71828^(1/a))) + (
       80. Sqrt[2.71828^(1/a) b^2])/Abs[-1. + 2.71828^(1/a)]], (a > 
       0 && b < 0) || (a < 0 && b > 0)]}
```

You could find functions satisfying your constraints and conditions,
e.g.

```
func[u_, v_] := {u, v, c, d} /. (sol /. {a -> u, b -> v})
```

Some functions:

```
func @@@ {{-1, 1}, {1, -1}, {2, -3}, {-2, 3}}
```

yields:

```
{{-1, 1, 123.32, 5.81478}, {1, -1, 203.32, -4.31478}, {2, -3, 
  1084.99, -12.9787}, {-2, 3, 844.995, 14.4787}}
```

Testing satisfies:

```
g[x_] := f[##, x] & @@ func[1, -1]
```

`g[0]` yields 1 and `g[80]` yields 0.5.

Or visualizing:

```
g[x_] := f[##, x] & @@ func[1, -1]
h[x_] := f[##, x] & @@ func[-1, 1]
i[x_] := f[##, x] & @@ func[2, -3]
j[x_] := f[##, x] & @@ func[-2, 3]
Plot[{g[x], h[x], i[x], j[x]}, {x, 0, 100}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{{0, 1}, {80, 0.5}}]}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation!